# How to POST ogg audio file to API in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, post

I am recording audio on a web page with a simple start and stop buttons. The file is stored as a blob. And I want this blob as file converted to base64 in the body of a POST call to my backend API.

I have tried the following code:

```js
'use strict'

var log = console.log.bind(console),
  id = val => document.getElementById(val),
  ul = id('ul'),
  gUMbtn = id('gUMbtn'),
  start = id('start'),
  stop = id('stop'),
  stream,
  recorder,
  counter = 1,
  chunks,
  media;



var mv = id('mediaVideo'),
  mediaOptions = {
    video: {
      tag: 'video',
      type: 'video/webm',
      ext: '.mp4',
      gUM: { video: true, audio: true }
    },
    audio: {
      tag: 'audio',
      type: 'audio/ogg',
      ext: '.ogg',
      gUM: { audio: true }
    }
  }



media = mediaOptions.audio;
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(media.gUM).then(_stream => {

  stream = _stream;
  id('btns').style.display = 'inherit';
  start.removeAttribute('disabled');
  recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

  recorder.ondataavailable = e => {

    chunks.push(e.data);
    let blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: media.type })
      , url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
      , li = document.createElement('li')
      , mt = document.createElement(media.tag)
      , hf = document.createElement('a');

    if (recorder.state == 'inactive') makeLink(url, li, mt, hf);
    log('data receiving');
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    console.log(reader);
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/rest/api/v1/audio/submit", (JSON.stringify(reader)), true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(reader));

  };


}).catch(log);


start.onclick = e => {
  start.disabled = true;
  stop.removeAttribute('disabled');
  chunks = [];
  recorder.start();
}


stop.onclick = e => {
  stop.disabled = true;
  recorder.stop();
  start.removeAttribute('disabled');
}



function makeLink(url, li, mt, hf) {

  mt.controls = true;
  mt.src = url;
  hf.href = url;
  hf.download = `${counter++}${media.ext}`;
  hf.innerHTML = `${hf.href}`;
  li.appendChild(mt);
  li.appendChild(hf);
  ul.appendChild(li);


}
```

Unfortunately I could not figure out how to POST after the recording in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an `onload`  event listener for when the `reader` has loaded the `data` in it after reading from `file`. In that event listener `handler`, you can make the `post` call.

```
let reader = new FileReader();
reader.addEventListener('load', e=>{
    console.log(reader.result);
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("POST"," http://localhost:8080/rest/api/v1/audio/submit", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhttp.send({data:reader.result});
});
reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
```

Also check the official documentation of [FileReader.readDataAsURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL)